# How to free gpu memory by deleting tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I create a tensor and put it on the GPU and don't need it later and want to free the GPU memory allocated to it; How do I do it?

```py
import torch
a=torch.randn(3,4).cuda() # nvidia-smi shows that some mem has been allocated.
# do something
# a does not exist and nvidia-smi shows that mem has been freed.
```

I have tried:

1. `del a`
2. `del a; torch.cuda.empty_cache()`

But none of them work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `del tensor` frees the memory from the GPU but does not return it to the device which is why the memory still being shown as used on `nvidia-smi`. You can create a new tensor and that would reuse that memory.

#### Sources

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-pytorch-objects-correctly-from-memory/947
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-torch-cuda-empty-cache/34232

Comment: To be clear, `del x` doesn't free the GPU memory of x. `del x` deletes the current reference to that tensor, which frees the GPU memory of x IFF that results in that variable having no references to it anymore.

For example


```
val = {'a': torch.randn(5, device='cuda')}
x = val['a']
del x
print(val['a'])
```

Comment: So what is the answer here? How to free GPU memory? That's super important in many cases.

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to explicitly free GPU memory. PyTorch will hold onto the memory and use it to allocate memory to new tensors.
Take a look at this [comment](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-pytorch-objects-correctly-from-memory/947/2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with the `tensor`:

```
tensor.detach()
tensor.grad = None
tensor.storage().resize_(0)
```